# Is it possible to change the NUnit test name convention on the entire fixture instead of on the test by test basis?

Tags: nunit

I want to use the template "{m}({1})". Now I can provide `TestName = "{m}({1})"` in each and every `TestCase` attribute. But this is too many repetitions. The `TestFixture` also has this parameter, but using it does not seem to have any effect:

```
    [TestFixture(TestName = "{m}({1})")]
    public class Tests
    {
...
    }
```

My question - is it possible to change the test name convention for all the tests in the given fixture by specifying it just once instead of in each and every `TestCase` attribute?

**EDIT 1**

I would like to keep using the `TestCase` attribute, even though using `TestCaseSource` does allow me to specify the template only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid setting name in each and every TestCase attribute by using `TestCaseSource` and `TestCaseData` as below example:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1 
{
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(MyDataClass), nameof(MyDataClass.TestCases))]
    public void DivideTest(int n, int d) 
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(3, n / d);
    }
}

public class MyDataClass 
{
    public static IEnumerable TestCases 
    {
        get 
        {
            yield return new MyTestCaseData(9, 3);
            yield return new MyTestCaseData(30, 10);
            yield return new MyTestCaseData(12, 4);
        }
    }
}

public class MyTestCaseData : TestCaseData 
{
    public MyTestCaseData(object arg1, object arg2) : base(arg1, arg2) 
    {
        SetName("{m}({1})");
    }
}
```

The `SetName` method of `TestCaseData` allows setting the name of an individual test case. So creating a new class derived from TestCaseData and setting name in constructor will avoid setting name for each TestCase attributes and also makes code cleaner.

**Solution 2: (Without using TestCaseSource and TestCases)**
It cannot be possible using `TestFixture` `TestName` property and using `TestCase` attribute natively. But same result can be achieved by creating and using custom attribute, for example `MyTestCaseAttr` - a class inherited from `TestCaseAttribute` and setting name in its constructor (there by avoiding to set name each time)

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [MyTestCaseAttr(12, 4)]
    public void DivideTest(int n, int d)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(3, n / d);
    }

    [MyTestCaseAttr(4, 5, 6)]
    public void AddTest(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(15, a + b + c);
    }
}

public class MyTestCaseAttr : TestCaseAttribute
{
    public MyTestCaseAttr(object arg1, object arg2) : base(arg1, arg2)
    {
        TestName = "{m}({1})";
    }

    public MyTestCaseAttr(object arg1, object arg2, object arg3) : base(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    {
        TestName = "{m}({1})";
    }
}
```

Comment: I intended my question to be specifically about the `TestCase` attribute. I like using it whenever possible due to its clarity and transparency. But my question did not communicate this intent clearly.

Comment: @mark updated answer to add 2nd solution. It doesn't use `TestCase` attribute but a custom attribute inherited from `TestCaseAttribute`, solution close to ideal one.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Using the `TestName` property as you have done simply sets the name of the test suite represented by the fixture class. In this case, the new name is "{m}({1})", which is used as-is, without making any substitutions.

The reason for this is that the special sequences used in a name template only apply to naming test cases, not to fixtures.

If you run using the NUnit3 console runner, you may specify a name format for use on **all test cases** in the assembly through the `--test-name-format` option.

Comment: I see. Too bad. I have a lot of data driven tests using the `TestCase` attribute and all of them provide the same exact TestName pattern. Would be very convenient to be able to specify the default TestName pattern on the fixture.